# Disable Scrolling When Canvas is in Use

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I'm creating an app that allows the user to add a signature by drawing it onto a canvas. From my previous research, I've decided to use a library I've discovered on Github called [SignatureView](https://github.com/zahid-ali-shah/SignatureView).

The signature view works fine until scrolling is enabled, at this point, the scrolling still takes place when the user is drawing, meaning the canvas moves during their input.

Due to this, I would like to disable scrolling when the user is interacting with the signature view. So far I've attempted to place the view in a nested scroll view and multiple xml attributes, but non of these seem to have any effect.

### The Layout XML File (With Irrelevant Views Omitted)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.jordan.promise.fragments.EnterSignature"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="56dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp">

    <com.kyanogen.signatureview.SignatureView
        xmlns:sign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/signature_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        sign:penSize="5dp"
        sign:backgroundColor="#ffffff"
        sign:penColor="#000000"
        sign:enableSignature="true"/>
</ScrollView>
```

### The OnCreate and OnCreateView Methods (Signature View isn't used anywhere else at the moment)

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enter_signature, container, false);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String defaultValue = getResources().getString(R.string.error_name);
    String firstName = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.user_first), defaultValue);

    //Greet User and provide instructionsView for entering signature
    helloFirst = view.findViewById(R.id.hello_first);
    instructionsView = view.findViewById(R.id.sig_instructions);
    String hello = getResources().getString(R.string.hello);
    String instructions = getResources().getString(R.string.enter_signature_instruction);
    helloFirst.setText(String.format("%s %s!", hello, firstName)); //Title/Welcome text
    instructionsView.setText(instructions);
    sigBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.signatureBtn);//Continue button, changes text if signature is present

    isDirty = false; //Solves API bug were isDirty only detects if a gesture is taking place

//Signature Capture
clearSignature = view.findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);
clearSignature.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        signatureView.clearCanvas();
        isDirty = false;
    }
});

//Check That Signature Field is not Empty
thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(1000);
                Log.i("handler" , "running");
                if(signatureView.isDirty() || isDirty) {
                    sigBtn.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.accept_sig));
                    isDirty = true;
                }
                else {
                    sigBtn.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.decline_sig));
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();

setHasOptionsMenu(true);

signatureView = view.findViewById(R.id.signature_view);


return view;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help. I hope this makes sense but please let me know if you need any clarifications or more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this. My solution was to create a separate layout for landscape, I then placed and sized the elements so that scrolling wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hi, I just saw this post in the review queue: please accept your answer so that the question is marked as resolved. It would be great if you could explain more your answer, so that if someone needs your solution the can understand it better ;)

Comment: It just came up in the review queue for me, too. You should take @FedericoGrandi's suggestion before someone comes along and deletes this answer.

Comment: Thank you both for letting me know and for understanding, I wasn't aware of how to mark a question as resolved a few days ago but I do now. @FedericoGrandi, I will update my answer when I'm back home and have access to the code :)